# After Code Virtualization return the empty value

Tags: c#, .net, eazfuscator

I don't know this is a bug or my mistake?, After Code Virtualization return the empty value.

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "Apply to type *: apply to member * when method or constructor: virtualization", Exclude = false)]

namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool valueWritten = false;
        private static int sharedValue = 0;

        private static void ThreadOneStart()
        {
            sharedValue = 1000;
            valueWritten = true;
        }

        private static void ThreadTwoStart()
        {
            if (valueWritten) Console.Write(sharedValue == 1000 ? "Good" : "Bad");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread threadOne = new Thread(ThreadOneStart);
            Thread threadTwo = new Thread(ThreadTwoStart);

            threadOne.Start();
            threadTwo.Start();

            threadOne.Join();
            threadTwo.Join();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `After Code Virtualization return the empty value.` what does this exactly mean in concrete specific terms

Comment: As there is no thread synchorization when accessing the two static fields, the result is undefined.

Comment: @KlausGütter Code Obfuscation should work like the original code.

Comment: Yes, but as the original code's behaviour is undefined, so is the behaviour of the obfuscated code. If you change the static bool to a suitable synchronization construct, e.g. a `ManualResetEvent`, both will work the same.

Comment: Even if there *were* synchronization around access to the static fields I'd suggest the outcome of this program is indeterminate, as there's no rule that says if I launch thread 1 then thread 2, that the instructions at the beginning of thread 1's thread procedure must have executed by the time thread 2 starts.  What's more interesting is if it could ever be "valid" for the program to print "Bad", as that would suggest an optimisation that changes the order of externally observable side-effects, which I'm pretty sure isn't ok.

Comment: @DylanNicholson I don't think it is forbidden for the compiler or the CPU to reorder the execution of the two assignments

Answer (score 0):

The given program has a race condition. This implies that the program behavior is undefined. It has nothing to do with Eazfuscator.NET.

Here is the right way do that:

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "Apply to type *: apply to member * when method or constructor: virtualization", Exclude = false)]

class Program
{
    private static bool valueWritten = false;
    private static int sharedValue = 0;
    private static ManualResetEvent ev = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static void ThreadOneStart()
    {
        sharedValue = 1000;
        valueWritten = true;
        ev.Set();
    }

    private static void ThreadTwoStart()
    {
        ev.WaitOne();
        if (valueWritten) Console.Write(sharedValue == 1000 ? "Good" : "Bad");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread threadOne = new Thread(ThreadOneStart);
        Thread threadTwo = new Thread(ThreadTwoStart);

        threadOne.Start();
        threadTwo.Start();

        threadOne.Join();
        threadTwo.Join();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with other Code Virtualizer's works without any problem so can not say the problem is the code.